# How can i get List of data from controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to get `Mutual-friend` from database, query and all code work well but get weird response from controller `AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap@7db3be92`. I can pass `List<DTO>` in controller as return type. I want to get `username` and other more column from database.

Here down is my code:

**DTO**

```
public interface ProfileJoin {
    public Integer getU_id();
    public String getUsername();
    public String getPassword();
}
```

**Query In Repository**

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT Distinct rgm.username, rm1.sender_id, rm1.receiver_id, pm.profile FROM registration_master as rgm INNER JOIN profile_master AS pm ON rgm.u_id = pm.user_id INNER JOIN request_master AS rm1 ON rgm.u_id = rm1.receiver_id INNER JOIN request_master AS rm2 ON rgm.u_id = rm2.receiver_id WHERE rm1.sender_id = ? AND rm1.status = ? AND rm2.sender_id = ? AND rm2.status = ?")
List<ProfileJoin> getMutualFriend(Integer Sender_id1, String Status1, Integer Sender_id2, String Status2);
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getmutualfriend/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getMutualFriend(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, HttpSession session, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws IOException
{
    List<ProfileJoin> getMutualFriend = service.getMutualFriend(Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("uid").toString()), "Accept", id, "Accept");
        if(getMutualFriend.size() > 0)
        {
            res.getWriter().print(getMutualFriend);
        }
        else
        {
            res.getWriter().print(" ");
        }
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/getmutualfriend/" + $("#friend_ID").attr("value"),
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res)
        }
    }); 
});
```

**My Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

I get perfect output when get `Mutual-friend` without using ajax...

[image]

Comment: In your query: use `?1`, `?2`, ... for the first, second,... parameter

Comment: Get same output. I think problem is not `?` or `?1`. I can try this without `ajax` it work well...

Comment: put `async: false,` after `type: "GET",` and check may be this will solve your problem

Comment: @KiranMistry `async: false` not working...  Problem is `how to get data like username, id, profile etc.. field` in ajax response like `success: function(res){console.log(res.username)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing data directly to the Response: `res.getWriter().print(getMutualFriend);` this will write the result of the `toString()` call on your object...

You should return the actual data: `List<ProfileJoin>`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getmutualfriend/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody // <--- will write result as json in the resoponse
public List<ProfileJoin> getMutualFriend(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, HttpSession session, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws IOException
{
   return service.getMutualFriend(Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("uid").toString()), "Accept", id, "Accept");

}
```

Then you can access the data via your JS

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "/getmutualfriend/" + $("#friend_ID").attr("value"),
       type: "GET",
       success: function(data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             console.log(data[i].u_id);
             console.log(data[i].username);
          }
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: I know this method but problem is not `how to send data` but problem is `how to get data like username, id, profile etc.. field` in ajax response like `success: function(res){console.log(res.username)}`

Comment: completed my answer

Comment: Get `Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract int com.pojo.Dto.ProfileJoin.getTotal_like()`... Because `@RequestBody` is missing but don't know which things put in requestbody

Comment: In your example, `ProfileJoin` does not have a `total_like`! But that error means that a NULL is being mapped to a `int` (primitive type), You should change this to an `Integer` that accepts nulls.

Comment: Without `@RequestBody` how i access `DTO` column name in ajax response

Comment: And `total_like` is already integer

Comment: Thanks Solved problem. I can declare primitive type `int` for `total_like` variable and change it to `Integer` code goes well... much appreciation for response @dirk_deyne